# Unity - Attach Component from a list to a GameObject

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, components

I have a list of components and I want to give each of my children one of the components in the list with it's specific values.

```
public List<ItemData> lootableItems = new List<ItemData>();
```

I want to assign that ItemData component to an Item Prefab which already has the ItemData Component in it. So I need to swap the components in some way, so it has the updated values from the list and not the default values.

Is there a simple way to do that change?
I was thinking of something like:

```
item.gameObject.AddComponent(lootableItems[i]);
```

Thanks for the anwers!

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of the old GameObjet.AddComponent(string) function.

You could use it like this:

```
    ItemData data = gameObject.AddComponent<ItemData>();
    data.Value1 = lootableItems[i].Value1;
    (...)
```

Then disable the old component.

Source: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/936452/attaching-a-script-at-runtime.html'

Another possible solution, would be to change the values of the old component, in the same manner. AKA:

```
ItemData data = gameObject.GetComponent<ItemData>();
data.Value1 = lootableItems[i].Value1
(...)
```

Comment: AddComponent(string) is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better practice not to modify your prefabs at runtime. Instead, instantiate your `Item` prefab, and then change the values of the `ItemData` component on the instantiated `GameObject`:

```
GameObject newItem = Instantiate(item) as GameObject;
if (newItem != nulll)
{
  ItemData itemData = newItem.GetComponent<ItemData>();
  if (itemData != null)
  {
    itemData.price = lootableItems[i].price; //example
  }
}
```